# self sizing tableview cell is not estimating heigh as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `tableView` cell with constrains that works nice in `Xcode 9`, and `iOS 10`, after upgrate to `iOS 12` and `Xcode 10` the self sizing stop working, `tableView` was unable to determinate the cell size.

[image: cell desing]

The cell designing is this with all constraints:

[image: cell constrains 1]
[image: cell constrins 2]

So setting by code the automatic dimension

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 196
}
```

The result is that I have to use the height for row with a number instead of `automaticDimension` to see the cell in `tableView`. So, I'm missing a constrain here or what.

Comment: can please check if you set bottom constraint with properly or not? and also try this tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 196
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: what you mean bottom constrain with properly. the border view has a bottom constrain but the last label does not have one? just top constrain

Comment: give the bottom constraint of last label.

Comment: ok thanks that was missing, i just dinnt note it, many thanks?

Comment: Did you solve it?